# Cluster network name resource 'Cluster Name' failed registration

Tags: clustering, aws, dns, windows-server

I have a fail-over cluster set between two Windows Server 2016 machines, and I'm seeing errors regarding the DNS record, both for the cluster itself and for any listener I try to add in SQL high availability.

> Cluster network name resource 'Cluster Name' failed registration of one or more associated DNS name(s) for the following reason:
>   DNS server failure.
>
> Ensure that the network adapters associated with dependent IP address resources are configured with at least one accessible DNS server.

[Properties of the cluster resource - img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNVGQ.png)

I've looked through [this link](https://www.itworld.com/article/2969325/virtualization/how-to-fix-hyper-v-cluster-error-1196-cluster-name-failed-registration.html) and I do see the 8.8.8.8 DNS on my machines, after the records for the domain DNS - these DNS settings are automatically pushed from our DC and I'm not sure I can change them. 
Has anyone experienced this? Is there another solution?

Answer (score 5):

I have come across this issue with my dev environment usually when during the setup of the cluster, i skip the warning for network binding. When you run a cluster validation, do you receive any warnings or errors on the network.
Anyways this link fix my issue. @Amr provided the solution to issue. 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c77c0b69-1f9d-4467-a0dd-6844e87e2d13/cluster-name-failed-to-update-the-dns-record?forum=exchange2010

Cause:

The cluster name resource which has been added to the DNS prior to setup active passive cluster ( or any type) need to be updated by the Physical nodes on behalf of the resource record itself. When the active node owns the resources it want to update the A record in the DNS database and DNS record which was created won’t allow any authenticated user to update the DNS record with the same owner

Solution:

Delete the existing A record for the cluster name and re-create it and make sure select the box says “Allow any authenticated user to update DNS record with the same owner name “Don’t worry about breaking anything , this has “ZERO” impact to cluster simply delete the A record and re-create as it is suggested here.

http://amradmin.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/event-id-1196-1119-dns-operation-refused-cluster-servers/

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped switching the cluster group (move-clustergroup -name "Cluster Group" -Node "Theothernode") and then switching it back