# Windows Cluster can't update DNS record

Tags: sql-server, clustering, windows-server, active-directory, dns

Setup:
Windows server 2016 standard edition.
SQL server 2016 standard edition.
2 nodes configured in a cluster without witness quorum.
all member of the same Active Directory domain.
1 Availability group for 1 Database only.
1 listener.
Creation went well, and any manual SQL or Cluster fail-over are working properly.

- dns domain: mydom.local
- Node1 machine Name: Mynode1
- Node2 machine Name: Mynode2
- Cluster name: mycluster
- Listener name: mySQLlistener
- Availability Group: MySQLAG

But since then I have regularly this error message in my Cluster logs:
`Source: Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering`

`Event ID: 1257`

```
Cluster network name resource failed registration of one or more associated DNS names(s) because the access to update the secure DNS Zone was denied.

Cluster Network name: 'MySQLAG_mySQLlistener'
DNS Zone: 'mydom.local'

Ensure that cluster name object (CNO) is granted permissions to the Secure DNS Zone.
```

I found this [ressource](https://fearthepanda.com/failovercluster/2018/07/20/FailoverCluster-Event-ID-1257-Every-15-Minutes/) and this [ressource](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194899/cluster-network-name-resource-cluster-name-failed-registration) which propose to recreate the CNO DNS record, but in the error message it is not the CNO for which it raise an error it is a Network name I don't use at all…  Built with the `Availability Group` + `ListenerName`.

Which is even more strange is that this network name is created with an "_" which is not "legal" for host names as per my [understanding](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-underscores-not-allowed-in-DNS-host-names).
so I'm wondering if I'm not having another issue…

Any idea why it raise this error would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed my issue by re-creating both DNS A record:
So in my example it is those two hostnames:
Cluster name: mycluster
Listener name: mySQLlistener

And when creating those records I have checked "allow any authenticated user to update DNS record with the same owner name".

Hope that helps.

Comment: when you say re-creating both DNS A record what do you mean? are you talking about the nodes of the cluster or something else? i've seen several versions of this question on different sites but thought everyone was referring to the name of the cluster object.

Comment: DNS A Record, are the DNS hostname referenced in the DNS server.
The Cluster object is stored on the Active Directory (AD) side it is a different object and AD rely on DNS for name resolution over the network.

Answer (score 0):

I found very useful the "kerberos configuration tool for sql server" from Microsoft, to find and fix SPN's issues.

Hope that helps.